# AWS S3 putBucketLifecycleConfiguration overwiting

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Please consider the following:

```js
const prefixes = ['prefix1', 'prefix2']
for (let documentPrefix of prefixes) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.DOCUMENT_BUCKET,
        LifecycleConfiguration: {
          Rules: [
            {
              Expiration: { Days: process.env.NUMBER_OF_DAYS },
              ID: documentPrefix,
              Status: 'Enabled',
              Filter: {
                Prefix: `${documentPrefix}/`,
              },
              NoncurrentVersionExpiration: {
                NoncurrentDays: process.env.NUMBER_OF_DAYS,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      };

      console.log(`Creating lifecycle rule with params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
      await s3.putBucketLifecycleConfiguration(params).promise();
}
```

I would expect a lifecycle rule in my bucket for each item of my array `prefixes` but instead there is only one rule for the last item in the array.

Can anyone explain why? The ID is different for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [putBucketLifecycleConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketLifecycleConfiguration-property) is a PUT operation which overwrites previous lifecycle settings by creating the new configuration.

So the fix is to send the all needed rules at once

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    
const prefixes = ['prefix1', 'prefix2'];
    
const rules = prefixes.map(documentPrefix => {
    return {
        Expiration: { Days: process.env.NUMBER_OF_DAYS },
        ID: documentPrefix,
        Status: 'Enabled',
        Filter: {
            Prefix: `${documentPrefix}`,
        },
        NoncurrentVersionExpiration: {
            NoncurrentDays: process.env.NUMBER_OF_DAYS,
        }
     }
});
    
async function run() {
    const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.DOCUMENT_BUCKET,
        LifecycleConfiguration: {
            Rules: rules
        },
    };
    console.log(`Creating lifecycle rule with params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
    await s3.putBucketLifecycleConfiguration(params).promise();
}

run();
```

As a result, two rules are finally applied (s3 bucket > management) [image: lifecycle management]

Comment: Thanks this is a perfect response! I thought each lifecycle config could have multiple rules.